# How to solve this uncomplicated equation (inspired by election arithmetic / election "math")?

Tags: systems-of-equations

[{(Disclaimer:  If it's more appropiate in a different section, please don't yell, just move it.}])

**Problem**:

*If a candidate Smith trails a candidate Jones by 20K votes, and there's 50K votes still outstanding, what is the percentage needed of the still outstanding 50K votes to overcome Jones?*

If:

- "x" < 1
- S = number of votes for Smith
- J = number of votes for Jones

then:

Yes, intuitively I **knów** the answer (x = 0,7 ), but how do I get there mathematically?
Something like:

x * S - (1-x) * J = 20
x * S + (1-x) * J = 50

I don't how to solve 2 equations with 3 unknowns, but I also don't know if that is a good mathematical representation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know $S,J$. You are given $J-S=20$ (measuring in thousands). Suppose Smith gets additional $x$ votes, then Jones gets the remaining $50-x$ votes. We need Smith to overcome Jones, so the only relation needed is$$(S+x)>(J+50-x)\\2x>J-S+50=70$$giving $x>35$. So Smith must get more than $35k$ of the remaining votes to beat Jones.